# logging into XTB broker using wrapper (error)

Tags: python, ssl

I am using wrapper for python prepared by XTB http://developers.xstore.pro/api/wrappers/2.5.0

Here is my code, just for check if login works properly. It should stream tick data. In config file stored my credentials:

```
#import libraries
from xAPIConnector import *
import config

#connect to API
user_id = config.user_id
pwd= config.pwd

client=APIClient()
resp=client.execute(loginCommand(user_id, pwd))
ssid=resp['streamSessionId']

sclient=APIStreamClient(ssId=ssid, tickFun=procTickExample)
sclient.subscribePrice('EURUSD')

time.sleep(60)

sclient.unsubscribePrice('EURUSD')
time.sleep(5)
sclient.disconnect()
client.disconnect()
```

Getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\robot.py", line 9, in <module>
    client=APIClient()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python\xAPIConnector.py", line 160, in __init__ 
    super(APIClient, self).__init__(address, port, encrypt)
  File "c:\Python\xAPIConnector.py", line 58, in __init__  
    self.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Have no idea how to deal with this. Any suggestions?

I am using Python 3.12 and none of my source files are named `ssl.py`.

Maybe I can change code in wrapper to handle it, but how?

Code below:

```
def __init__(self, address, port, encrypt = False):
    self._ssl = encrypt 
    if self._ssl != True:
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    else:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
    self.conn = self.socket
    self._timeout = None
    self._address = address
    self._port = port
    self._decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    self._receivedData = ''
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 which python version should I use to cover this funcjonality?

Comment: As the newest answer in the linked duplicate says, Python 3.12 removes this function from the standard library. Either use an earlier version or follow the linked recommendations to update your code (https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#ssl).

Comment: *instead, create a ssl.SSLContext object and call its ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket method.*